# How to increase the size of input box in MS Access reports or forms based on user input?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a text box in MS Access Report which is set to unbound. I want to be able to collect an address in that field which can be any length based upon the customer address. I right clicked the box and set the size property to "To-Fit". However this did not do anything at all. The report needs to be printed which is why I cannot have a part of an address cut off because of the size of the text box.

Is there a way to make the size of the text box dynamic?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such feature for reports. For form controls you could use `Horizontal Anchor` but not for reports.

So you have two possibilities to let your adress not be cutted:

## 1: Let it grow vertically

To achieve this you would have to set the property `Can grow` of both, the textbox **and** the containing section to `Yes`.

If the text now doesn't fit in the textbox it will be resized in height.

## 2: Control it via VBA

You could use the `format event` to control the width of the textbox via VBA.

Here is an example of how to do this, but I didn't ever try it.
Unfortunately it is in `mdb` format, so you would need an older Microsoft Access Version (I expect Microsoft Access 2007 should be able to, 2003 for sure) to open it and grab the code.

http://www.lebans.com/autosize_textbox.htm

It uses Windows APIs and could be not so easy to get it running.

What it does (just the steps):
It first calculates the width of the text to be displayed in respect to the current font, fontsize and its properties.
Knowing this the control can be resized regarding.